# Checking Java Collection Generic Type for an Empty Collection

Tags: java

I want to implement the following function:

```
public boolean checkType(Vector<?> vec)
{
  // return true if its Vector<Integer> and false otherwise
}
```

How can I check the vector elements type ? 
**Note that** the vector might be empty thus I can't check if the first element is "instanceof" Integer or String ...

*EDIT:*

Well, I had something in mind I don't know if it will work or not

Can I implement the checkType function as following:

```
public <T> boolean checkType(Vector<T> vec)
{
  // return true if T is Integer and false otherwise
}
```

is it possible to check if T is Integer ?!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: if the vector might be empty, i think there is no point in checking the generic type

Comment: And what to return if the vec was for example `Vector<Long>`? true, false, half-true? This isn't a very good design to be honest.

Comment: @anand, i just wanted to know if there is way to check for the generic type without checking the type of a random element in the vector ...

Comment: @Natix, you can return false if its not Vector<Integer> ... its not the point here really... can u check for the generic type in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Generic type parameters** are unrecoverable (except for some special cases) at runtime because of [*type erasure*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). This means that at runtime, both `Vector<Integer>` and `Vector<String>` are simply just `Vector`s and their elements are just `Object` references.

Only the actual runtime classes (discoverable by `instanceof` checks as you pointed out) of the individual elements make the notion of the element type, otherwise the Vector itself has no idea what it's element type is.

So basically, an empty vector of any type is equal to **empty** vector of any other type. It is even safe to cast it like this:

```
Vector<String> noStrings = (Vector<String>) new Vector<Integers>();
```

However there is one problem, because although you can say that **empty** vector conforms to any required element type, this statement stands only **as long as the vector stays empty**. Because if you do this:

```
Vector<Integer> ints = new Vector<Integer>(); // empty
Vector<String> strings = (Vector<String>) ints; // unchecked warning, but still possibly ok
ints.add(1); // here comes trouble
String s = strings.get(1); // oh oh, ClassCastException
```

### EDIT:

To answer you second question: No it isn't possible to write anything like this:

```
public <T> boolean checkType(Vector<T> vec) {
    return T instanceof Integer; // impossible
    return T == Integer; // impossible
    return T.class == Integer.class // impossible
    return vec instanceof (Vector<Integer>); // impossible
}
```

However you can write a method that uses a class token as an input parameter:

```
static <T> boolean checkElementType(Collection<?> collection, Class<T> elementType) {
    for (Object object : collection) {
        if (!elementType.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
List<?> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<?> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, "a");
System.out.println(checkElementType(list1, Integer.class)); // true
System.out.println(checkElementType(list2, Integer.class)); // false
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer :) ... I edited my question please take a look ... if I am mistaken please inform me

Comment: @TeFa: The answer to your updated question is still "no, that's not possible."

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who tells you that this is possible at all is wrong. At runtime, there is no way to tell whether an empty Vector was a `Vector<Integer>` or `Vector<Rainbow>`.

That's more or less the *definition* of type erasure.

Comment: So you mean that its not possible to check for the generic type unless there is at least one element in the collection ?

Comment: Even if there are elements, this check is unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

Because of type erasure, this is not possible.

Even if the vector is not empty, the collections library gives no real protection against putting things of different types in:

```
    Vector v = new Vector<Integer>();
    v.add("foo");
    System.out.println(v.get(0));
```

will run without error and nicely print the string value that shouldn't have been allowed.

Thus any attempt to determine the generic type at run-time, even by checking the type of the first element, is not reliable.

What you can do in your own generic code is to add a constructor argument and a field holding the value, so that your code *does* know the type at runtime.

This tactic would be difficult to apply to the entire collections library, but a start at it for `Vector` would be:

```
public class TypedVector<E> extends Vector<E> {

    private Class<E> genericClass;

    public TypedVector(Class<E> clazz) {
        super();
        this.genericClass = clazz;
    }

    // many other constructors ... but probably not all of them

    public Class<?> getGenericClass() {
        return genericClass;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        if (!(genericClass.isAssignableFrom(e.getClass())))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect class");
        return super.add(e);
    }

    // many other overrides for run-time type safety
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public boolean checkType(Vector<?> vec)
{
  if(!vec.isEmpty())
  {
    if("String".equals(vec.get(0).getClass().getSimpleName()))
             return false;
    else if("Integer".equals(vec.get(0).getClass().getSimpleName()))
             return true;               
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: -1: The question quite specifically asked about an *empty* vector and included notes clearly indicating the OP knew how to do it for a non-empty vector.